# Am getting cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Type&’ to an rvalue of type 'Type'

Tags: c++11, vector

Here's my class

```
    class DriverPoint
{
public:

  DriverPoint(){};
  DriverPoint (DriverPoint& dp) = default;
  DriverPoint(double lat, double lon)
  {
    _lat = lat;
    _lon = lon;
  }
  double _lat;
  double _lon;
};

// main
    DriverPoint driverPoint(lat, _long); 
        vector.push_back(driverPoint);
```

When i try to compile it am getting

cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘DriverPoint&’ to an rvalue of type ‘DriverPoint’

Comment: You most likely want `DriverPoint (const DriverPoint& dp) = default;` Note the `const`. In fact, I don't think you need to explicitly mention the copy constructor at all - you should be able to drop this line entirely, one would be implicitly defined regardless.

Answer (score 3):

### When adding an element to std containers it is *copied* (or moved, in case of an rvalue).

So the call to: `vec.push_back(driverPoint)` calls internally the copy constructor of DriverPoint.

There are two overloads for [`vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

```
(1) void push_back( const T& value );
(2) void push_back( T&& value );
```

(1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
(2) value is moved into the new element.

Overload 2 is for *rvalue reference* (so it requires T to be *MoveInsertable* which in this case means having a move constructor). Note that it is not a forwarding reference here, since T is a template parameter of the class and not of the function.

Your call to *push_back* goes to the first overload, as the passed parameter (the object *driverPoint*) is a *non-const lvalue* which can bind to *const lvalue* (the parameter *const T&* expected in overload 1 of *push_back*). Wait... the copy constructor is not called yet! But, inside *vector::push_back* there is an attempt to create a copy of T, by sending it to the copy constructor as const, which fails if the copy constructor is missing the 'const' on its parameter.

### Step 1 - fixing the copy ctor

Adding of course 'const' to the parameter of the copy constructor would fix this: `DriverPoint(const DriverPoint& driverPoint)`

However, above fix is not the correct one (wait, it is correct, if you want a copy constructor make sure the parameter you expect is const lvalue ref - but in this case the copy constructor is not required at all...).

### Step 2 - removing the copy ctor

The problem with having a copy constructor that is not required is that you are implicitly deleting the default move constructor (and others, following the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Note that the current code doesn't even allow adding an rvalue into the vector: `vec.push_back(DriverPoint{})` would also fail with the same compilation error.

If you would fix the copy constructor to: `DriverPoint(const DriverPoint& driverPoint)` both adding lvalue and adding rvalue to the vector by calling *push_back* would work, but both would go through the copy ctor and not through move, as you didn't implement move and the default move is implicitly deleted if you declare any single one of the five: destructor, copy ctor, copy assignment, move ctor or move assignment.

If you wish to add copy ctor, e.g. for debugging, but still to preserve the default move operations, add:

```
DriverPoint(DriverPoint&&) = default; // move ctor
DriverPoint& operator=(DriverPoint&&) = default; // move assignment
```

### Rule of Zero

The best way to go with types that do not require special care for copying or destruction, i.e. do not require user implementation of any of the three: destructor - copy ctor - copy assignment operator, is to go with the *Rule of Zero* -- do not declare any of the five - which would give you the defaults for all five.

**Note that it is a common mistake in actual production code** -- declaring a destructor, a copy constructor or an assignment operator, thus implicitly deleting the move operations. This may hurt performance badly in quite a quiet way. Move may be used in many places without the programmer's notice, e.g. by std containers. And if it is implicitly deleted the inner fields of the type (e.g. strings, vectors, etc.) would always be copied, even when can be moved. It is especially common in code base that started before C++11, when move operations were not introduced yet but can be also found in new code.